# Unit Vector Displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

A particle starts from the origin at $t = 
 0$ with a velocity of $+4.0\mathbf{j} \text{ m/s}$ and moves in the $xy$ plane
with a constant acceleration of $(6.0\mathbf{i} + 4.0\mathbf{j}) \text{ m/s}$. At the instant the $x$ coordinate of the particle is
$27 \text{ m}$, what is the value of its $y$ coordinate?

I'm trying to teach myself physics, and came across this question. If the initial velocity is $4\mathbf{j}$, does that mean it is $0\mathbf{i}$ in the $x$ direction? All I can think of doing is setting up an equation like $27 = (1/2)(6.0\mathbf{i})t^2$ but that doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your one specific question: Yes, if the initial velocity is $4\hat{j}\ \mathrm{m/s}$, then the x-component is zero ($0\hat{i}$).

Additionally, it seems to me that you have fallen into the trap that physics is simply "finding the right equation."  Be careful to avoid that!

Also, your units for acceleration are wrong.

You should go back and spend more time thinking about the concepts of position, velocity, and acceleration and how they relate to each other.  Spend some time following through example problems (in a good book), making sure you understand how each step is related to the conceptual relationship.  Don't go "equation hunting." Go "concept hunting."

EDIT: The concept you are dealing with is *constant acceleration motion.*  Keep in mind that

- a classical particle will be at one point $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ in 3-space at one instant of time (t).
- velocity is the time rate of change (derivative) of position
- acceleration is the time rate of change  of velocity
  If acceleration is constant, it's an easy integral to do to find velocity, but remember to apply initial conditions:
  $$\int\mathrm{d}\vec{v} = \int \vec{a} \mathrm{d}t$$
  $$\vec{v}(t) + \vec{C} = \vec{a}t$$
  $$\vec{v}(0) + \vec{C} = 0$$
  $$\vec{v}(t) - \vec{v}(0)=\vec{a}t$$

The integral to find position \vec{r} simply involves this linear function:
$$\vec{r}(t)-\vec{r}(0)=\int \vec{v}(t) \mathrm{d}t. $$
This will give you a general approach to solving *constant acceleration* problems.  The basic equations are the same every time.  You have 3 components of space position, three components of velocity, three components of acceleration, all determined at the *same* value of time.  You have information for t=0 for all the others, and you have one position at some other time.  Once you have these concepts established, set up a *system* of equations and solve.  In your example, you know $\vec{r}(0)$, $\vec{v}(0)$, and $\vec{a}$. You also know $x(t_1)$. You want to find $y(t_1)$. Let all the $z$ components be zero, because you have no information about $z$.

Comment: My book doesn't explain this type of problem, I found it on a practice test online. I also can't find any examples of this type of problem online. It seems like I could take the integral of acceleration with the velocity as the constant and then then take the integral again to find displacement?  I'm not sure what to integrate with respect to, or how to deal with the i's and j's. Do you have any hints to get me started?

Comment: Sounds like you need to get a new book.  This is a *very* standard problem.   I'll edit my answer to point out the concept.

Comment: Why the drive-by down vote?